# Allow user to add a reference to another solution and invoke methods from it

Tags: c#, dynamic, reference

I have a tool that I am designing to test another application. I am able to reference the version of the solution under test that I have on my machine and invoke methods from it without issue. What I would like to do is allow the user to select (possibly in an OpenFileDialog) the latest version of the software solution and have the tool reference the current version rather than the version I have been using to design with on my computer.

Assuming that the method names under test would not change, can I create a sort of "dynamic" reference that is set by the user and then in turn these methods can be invoked from? Or should I be thinking more along the lines of config files or resources? Thanks

Comment: You can dynamically load assemblies at runtime (using `Assembly.LoadFrom`), but the tougher issue is that you won't have intellisense or be able to just call `SomeClass.MethodName()`, you'll have to do it through reflection and invoking.

Comment: That could work. If I use the Assembly.LoadFrom() will I have to designate a set location for the solution under test so that each time the user wants to reference a new version of the solution that they would load it in this designated spot? Does that make sense?

Comment: No, you can use the open file dialog to choose the location and pass the location of the assembly to the `Assembly.LoadFrom()` method. If you want to be able to load/unload versions of the assembly, you need to create a new AppDomain, don't load it into the current AppDomain otherwise you can't unload it and you'll get an error when you load it again.

Comment: Awesome. Can I do this for .exe files as well? Is there another method for that, or does it have to be a .dll?

Comment: An exe is no different than a DLL except it has some entry points and a main method. You can load executables with this as well.